# Need advice on how to access a database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database

I am using ASP classic and JavaScript. I have a function in JavaScript that creates new downloadable PDF files using the jsPDF library and I need to access some values from a database, but I read that JavaScript is not safe, nor the most common method to access a database. I need advice on how to access those values safele and correctly.

Comment: Ajax those values from the server, baby! :)

Comment: Well, you don't. You'll need ajax.

Comment: You do not necessarily need AJAX, but the server should speak to the database and forward the data to the client (possibly in the initial page markup).

Comment: You should use jQuery for this, it's great !

Comment: Ok I checked the AJAX and i thank you a lot for the answer.. There is one more problem - how do I send back the values?